# Laravel 7.6.2 app.js error app.js:3449 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I using Laravel 7.6.2 as mentioned, and I keep getting the error in browser console as shown in picture below when I click on my navbar toggle button.

[image]

[image]

Here is the css and script files used:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Serif:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/jomkurus.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Plugins -->
<script src="{{asset('fontawesome/js/all.js')}}"></script>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Thank you for your advice in advance.

Comment: Can you share your jQuery code used for the menu toggle?

Comment: Hi Harun, thank you for your comment, I have found the root cause of this issue, seem like it is because of the jQuery 3.5.0 version issue.

At this moment, the solution is downgrade jQuery to 3.4.1 version. The discussion can be found here.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30553

I have tried it and it works! Thank you for your time to comment on my question, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the root cause of this issue, seem like it is because of the jQuery 3.5.0 version issue. At this moment, the solution is downgrade jQuery to 3.4.1 version. The discussion can be found here. github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30553 I have tried it and it works!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery released 3.5.1, that fixed this bug ([jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2020/05/04/jquery-3-5-1-released-fixing-a-regression/)).

You can update this module in your project:

```
npm install jquery@3.5.1
npm run dev
```